# Python variable not changing

Tags: python

I have a simple `for` loop which loops through the contents of an int list and multiplies every non zero int. I store this value in the variable `mult`. However, `mult` is not changing. What's wrong?

```
def answer(l):
    mult = 0
    for i in l:
        if i != 0:
            if mult == 0:
                mult *= i
    return mult

print (answer([3,4,5]))
```

Comment: "max is not changing" ... What is "max" here??

Comment: `if mult == 0` - you'll multiply by zero - is that what you want?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: should replace first mult = 0 with mult = 1. should remove 2nd if statement.

Answer (score 3):

If you are setting mult to 0 then mult *=anything will always be 0. Try giving it an initial value of 1

Answer (score 2):

The error probe statement in your code is **mult = 0** that end results with 0 for any input.... Change that statement with **mult = 1**

```
def answer(l):
    mult = 1
    for i in l:
        if i != 0:
            mult *= i
    return mult

print (answer([3,4,5]))
```

Output : 60

Comment: shouldnt we initialize mult to 1 not 0?

Comment: Yes sir @Stephen Quan. That's what i did, if there is still any issue in code please let me know

Answer (score 2):

As @yourPublicDisplayName already pointed out, anything times 0 is 0.
You're used to using `0` from running sums.  However, this is a running *product*.  For a sum, you begin with the additive identity element, 0; for products, you have to start with the *multiplicative* identity element, 1.

Also, do *not* check to see whether your variable is still at the starting value (`mult == 0`): this would simply stall your progress at one element: once you change that value, you won't include any further non-zero numbers.  More simply:

```
def answer(l):
    mult = 1
    for i in l:
        if i != 0:
            mult *= i
    return mult

print (answer([3,4,5]))
```

Output:

```
60
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you are trying to figure out why the variable `mult` is not changing. It is declared as `0`, which stays alway the same with any computations. You might change it to any other values than `0`.

Your code must be like:

```
def answer(l):
    mult = a # a as given value
    for i in l:
        if i != 0:
            if mult == a:
                mult *= i
    return mult

print (answer([3,4,5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes in above code.
 1. First mult variable should be =1 
 2. if mult == 1 this condition will not change your value, after first multiplication condition will never satisfied if first value is not 1

Modification in above

```
>>> def answer(l):
...     mult = 1
 ..     for i in l:
...         if i != 0:
...             mult *= i
...     return mult
...
>>> print (answer([3,4,5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse 0 multiplies with anything would be zero. Below is the shorter version of what you are trying to do using [accumulate](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.accumulate)

```
from operator import add, mul
from toolz.itertoolz import accumulate
import numpy as np
a=np.array([3,4,5])
list(accumulate(mul, a[np.nonzero(a)]))[-1] #60
```